# Silverlight "Animation target not specified."

Tags: silverlight, animation, storyboard

I have this code, but i can't use that because this is throws exception when i call sb.Begin():

> Animation target not specified.

```
    public void TableCardAnimation(UserControl cardControl, double Height, double Width)
    {
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation animHeight = new DoubleAnimation();
        animHeight.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
        animHeight.From = cardControl.Height;
        animHeight.To = Height;
        sb.Children.Add(animHeight);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animHeight, cardControl);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animHeight, new PropertyPath("(Height)"));


        DoubleAnimation animWidth = new DoubleAnimation();
        animWidth.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
        animWidth.From = cardControl.Width;
        animWidth.To = Width;
        sb.Children.Add(animWidth);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animWidth, cardControl);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animHeight, new PropertyPath("(Width)"));

        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Where i'm wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's just a typing error.

in the line:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animHeight, new PropertyPath("(Width)"));
```

you've set target property for the `animHeight` secondary, but your animWidth target property is still unset. You might want to do:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animWidth, new PropertyPath("(Width)"));
```

And why you use `"(Width)"` instead just `"Width"`?